# Trying to run a powershell command from bat script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run the following powershell command from a .bat script

```
[void] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(10,"Copied!","Map names have been copied to the clipboard",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

the code is intended to produce a simple balloon notification in the bottom right hand corner of the screen

I have tested the code in powershell and it works just fine there, however i cant get it to work in cmd / via a .bat script

i dont want to have to point to a seperate powershell file, i need it all to run from within this one script

I have realised that i need to address that this is a powershell script at the beginning of the script so that it runs correctly so i have modified it to the following:

```
powershell -Command "& {[void] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms"); [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing"); $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon; $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information; $notify.visible = $true; $notify.showballoontip(10,"Copied!","Map names have been copied to the clipboard",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None);}"
```

from everything i have read on here for people with similar problems this should work, i can get cmd to run other simple powershell commands which appear to work just fine, such as

```
powershell -Command "& { Get-Process }"
```

so what am i doing wrong here?
when i run the above code i get the following error message on cmd

```
At line:1 char:54
+ & {[void] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(System.Windows.F ...
+                                                      ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:54
+ ... eflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(System.Windows.Forms); [refl ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'System.Windows.Forms' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:3
+ & {[void] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(System.Windows.F ...
+   ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:1 char:74
+ ... flection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(System.Windows.Forms); [refle ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:120
+ ... m.Windows.Forms); [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(System.D ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:120
+ ... s); [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(System.Drawing); $noti ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'System.Drawing' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:134
+ ... ); [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(System.Drawing); $notif ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:300
+ ... ormation; $notify.visible = $true; $notify.showballoontip(10,Copied!, ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:300
+ ... n; $notify.visible = $true; $notify.showballoontip(10,Copied!,Map nam ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Copied!' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:307
+ ... ; $notify.visible = $true; $notify.showballoontip(10,Copied!,Map name ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

is it something to do with the syntax i am using? maybe to do with spaces or something?

Comment: Change every nested doublequote, i.e. all except the first and last to ```\"```. e.g. ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "[void] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(\"System.Windows.Forms\");[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(\"System.Drawing\");$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon;$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information:$notify.visible = $true;$notify.showballoontip(10,\"Copied!\",\"Map names have been copied to the clipboard\",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)"```

Comment: Jumping through hoops to run powershell from batch. You should _really_ just run the whole thing from powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your PowerShell script and execute it from a batch file with this hybrid method, and you will don't worry about any escape special character anymore :

---

```bat
<# : Batch Script Section
@rem # The previous line does nothing in Batch, but begins a multiline comment block in PowerShell. This allows a single script to be executed by both interpreters.
@echo off
Title Embed And Execute Powershell Script with a Batch file in Hybrid Mode & Mode 70,3
cd "%~dp0"
Color 1B & echo( & Echo(
Echo(     Please Wait ... Loading PowerShell script is in progress ...
Powershell -executionpolicy bypass -Command "Invoke-Expression $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~f0'))"
EndLocal
pause
goto:eof
#>
# Powershell Script Section begin here...
# Here we execute our powershell commands...
[void] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")  | Out-Null
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(10,"Copied!","Map names have been copied to the clipboard",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

---

Here is an example that I used this hybrid method : [SpeedTest_Hackoo_Ookla.bat](https://pastebin.com/LYLUJR6e)